# Add a new Stack Exchange login

Tags: discussion, display-names, network-profile

I have a login already using Facebook credentials. But I need another login on Stack Exchange itself. It's because I use my friend's Android device to access my account, and it does not let me in anyway...

I had been using it on the web using my laptop only, since my phone is a Windows Phone.

There is an option in the app for an SE username and password. But they are probably not as same as Facebook login.

How can I do it?

Comment: Don't put the solution as part of the question. Please post this as a new answer, and don't add "SOLVED" to the title. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No answers to questions marked as duplicate :(

Comment: Oh right, this question is closed, sorry about that. Is your solution different than the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/152859)? If so, how?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's similar, but, i already had an e-mail from facebook! so i need not add a new one as in the post you tagged. Also, I have  a direct link to the recovery. Quite straight process (3 steps)!!

Comment: Well, if you think it is different enough you can add another answer in there.

Answer (score 2):

Not too difficult.  Go to your profile and click on "Network Profile."

You should see something like this (personalized for you, obviously):

[image]

Click on "my logins."

At the bottom of the dialog, you should see "add more logins..."; click on it.  Then click on "Log in with Stack Exchange" and create an account.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this does not work. Stack Exchange OpenID can't be used with other providers as far as I know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, hmm, you could be right.

Comment: See the dupes. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, argh, there are always dupes on meta... ;)

Comment: Yup, and I'm hunting for them... :D